# Count specific string within text file [whitespace noise]

Tags: regex, text, whitespace

I want to get all the occurences of a specific string, e.g. `police officer` in a text file, the text file has a lot of whitespace and it could potentially look like this:

```
T h e  r a p i s t  r a n  f r o m  t h e  p o l i c e 
o f f i c e r, d o w n  M a i n  S t r e e t.
```

Or in the simplest form:

```
The rapist ran from the police officer, down Main Street.
```

I am knowledgeable in VBA or PHP, but would be open to other quick solutions.

I was thinking about Regex, but wasnt sure, if there was a way.

Comment: This looks like UTF-16. You can open the file as UTF-16 and read it as per normal.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I already got the text files and they are readable

Comment: Are you saying that there could be one or more spaces or tabs between letters in a word?  Do you need to maintain word boundaries? And are you looking for strings (parts of words, e.g.) or full words and phrases consisting of full words, or a mix of full words and parts of words (e.g. ignoring plurals)?  You'd want "police officers" to satisfy a search for "police officer".

Comment: @Spurious: Some encoding are designed to make ASCII text readable. I just suggest the possibility that the text is encoded with UTF-16, which is quite similar to your case.

Comment: nhahtdh: I extracted the text from a pdf file. There might be the possibility that it is UTF-16, but cant I account for those possibilites (not all of them are in that format) in another way?

Tim: Yes, there could be a tab, new line, space and whatever else whitespace character in between.
Ideally, I would be looking for partial words as well, so yes, police officers should work as well with a search for police officer.

Comment: Any other possiblities?

Answer (score 1):

You can put spaces in regex, your search string here would be something like `p\s*o\s*l\s*i\s*c\s*e\s+o\s*f\s*f\s*i\s*c\s*e\s*r\s*`. If you want to include tabs, you can change `\s*` to `[\s\t]*`. Of course, you can create these search strings automatically.

If you want to try out regular expressions first, there are numerous online resources for this, for example http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Your method will have the same problem as the other answer. By allowing arbitrary spacing, you totally ignore the word boundary. `The rapist` vs. `Therapist` example also applies here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (in php):

1) Read contents of the file into a string (or the contents of the line if you're doing it line by line)

2) Use str_replace() to strip any white space from the string

3) Use strpos() to see if 'policeofficer' is in the string. (Note that you'll need to strip spaces from the input too).

4) return the result of strpos (Note that you'll need to use === to test).

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do this, but it should work.

Comment: Strip all whitespaces? It is going to be a disaster since there might be more than one way to interpret a stream of words without proper spacing with a context-less parser. You destroy the word boundary by removing all whitespaces. "The rapist" vs. "Therapist" - the meaning changes 180 degree.

Comment: You have a good point. However, depending on the application of this, that might not be an issue.  For instance, if the application had a set list of search terms and none of them formed other words when stripped of spaces.  If this would be a concern then the only other option I know of is to use regex.  There are already other answers that addressed how to do it with regex.

Comment: The other answer still run into the same problem. The best way is to find some clue to normalize the input before searching. (And it IS an issue. You can try reading some text and see whether you can find some other words within - it is quite common actually).

Comment: I wasn't claiming it's not an issue, but rather MIGHT not be in certain situations.  And you're right, if you use * in the regex for the spaces, you'd run into the same problem.